# Boost 1.60.0.tar.bz2 not extracting correctly

Tags: boost, terminal

Forgive me for any silly mistakes but I'm very inexperienced.  I have a file boost_1_60_0.tar.bz2 and am trying to extract it to /usr/local using the command

```
tar --bzip2 -xf ~/Downloads/boost_1_60_0.tar.bz2
```

When I try to do this it gives me over a thousand errors each with the same basic format like this example: boost_1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_base/: Failed to create dir 'boost_1_60_0'Can't create 'boost_1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port_base'

When I do this I have cd'd into usr/local.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @janm I have extracted the file correctly now however running ./bootstrap.sh as described in the getting started guide is not working.  I have previously already extracted boost, but I botched that extraction by not extracting it to the right place on my computer, and now it appears difficult to use.  Any advice?

Comment: I have tried using sudo chmod 755 bootstrap.sh, but it says that bootstrap.sh does not exist.  Where should I go to reset the executable?

Comment: Are you typing "./bootstrap.sh" and not just "bootstrap.sh"? The current directory is not normally in your search path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission to write into /usr/local as an ordinary user.

Instead you should extract to a build directory, for example under your home directory, and then follow the boost build and installation instructions in the "getting started" page. That will put the files into /usr/local with a reasonable structure.

Comment: @wfehrn Yes, sudo would work for the extraction. However, you will then get the wrong directory structure and no compiled libraries.